# Distorted / delayed sound

Tags: audio

Hi I am not very good with Linux, but I have some experience. I have it up and running, but the audio either from HDMI or audio jack is coming out distorted and is often delayed. I have been distro hopping trying to find a linux that has no audio issues (zero sound at all), and this is the first that actually has some sound.

I have the following computer:

Ryzen 9 5950x
3090 using the driver available in the app center 510.60.02
64 gigs of ram

Thanks :)

Comment: OP here. I fixed it myself with this https://forum.level1techs.com/t/delayed-sound-output-ubuntu-elementary-os-solved/115034